# Large file upload using Flask and Celery

Tags: python, flask, celery, long-running-processes

I am trying to implement a large file upload in `flask` using `celery`. I have a function that saves the file stream to the disk as a **celery task** but, my implementation requires the use of the `request` context inside of my task function. I have done my research and implemented the solutions provided on the links given [on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31383953/how-to-keep-a-request-context-in-a-celery-task-in-python-flask?noredirect=1&lq=1) but, this doesn't seem to work with my version of **celery** which is `4.1.0`

Here is what I am doing

This is my *task*

```py
@task(name="app.save_operation")
def save_operation():
    content = request.files["content"]
    content.save(
        content.filename)
    content.stream.close()
    return
```

This is the `@task` wrapper

```py
def task(**kwargs):
    def decorator(func):
        @celery_helper.task(**kwargs)
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
            with app.test_request_context():
                return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapped
    return decorator
```

And this is the API handler function where I am calling this task

```py
@app.route("/upload", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def upload():
    if (request.method == "POST"):
        filename = request.files["content"].filename
        task_id = save_operation.delay()
        return "upload started for "+filename
```

``
This should work fine in theory but, when I do this, **celery** throws a `BadRequestKeyError` which essentially means that the `request` object which is being referred in the `save_operation()` task is not being passed properly. I am not able to figure out why this is happening and I have reached a roadblock with my research.

I would really like some insights on this.

Comment: Isn't it possible to just pass `request` (or its components) as arguments when calling `save_operation.delay()`? Instead of relying on the Flask context.

Comment: @TomášLinhart the thing is that the `.delay()` only accepts `json` values and I am able to serialize the `request` object using `jsonpickle` but, when I try to de-serialize it, it throws a runtime error.